# Why does SASS compile unwanted / unused code

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass, scss-lint

I am learning SASS and trying out some examples. I have some problem understanding Selector Sequence and why SASS merges them.

In a real world scenario the output can have unwanted css. For eg:-

```
a{
    color: #0086B3;
    &:hover{
      text-decoration: none;
   }
 }

#footer a{
  color: #a61717;
}

.head-links{
  @extend a;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

This block of code complies to :-

```
a, .head-links {
  color: #0086B3; 
}
a:hover, .head-links:hover {
   text-decoration: none; 
}

#footer a, #footer .head-links {
  color: #a61717; 
}

.head-links {
  font-weight: bold; 
}
```

The problem is that

```
#footer .head-links
```

might never be used. So what is the point of merging selector sequence if it is not required.

How can I avoid this.How can I make it extend only :-

```
a{
   color: #0086B3;
   &:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
   }
 }
```

Would that require me using a class instead...

Answer (score 2):

because you are extending the element `a` here:

```
@extend a;
```

if you remove it, then the SASS won't "merge" them.

you have `footer a` and when extending the `a` in `.head-links` it will add `#footer .head-links` to the already existing rule `#footer a`

Which means it will extend to ANY `a` in the CSS, not just the selector `a` alone

**UPDATE**

> How can I avoid this.How can I make it extend only :-
>
> `a{
>   color: #0086B3;
>      &:hover{`
>   
>       `text-decoration: none;
>    } 
>   }`
>
> Would that require me using a class instead...

yes you would need to use a class or an ID for that.

something like this:

```
.uniqueclass{
   color: #0086B3;
   &:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
   }
 }
```

here is a [SASS demo](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/da69df0c69c74255688a2c567144e1a7)

Comment: well yes...but my point is - only this block of code should be extended :- a{
    color: #0086B3;
    &:hover{
      text-decoration: none;
   }
 }